# copy/cut/paste functions in my notepad type program

Tags: python, notepad

I am writing a notepad type program and am unable to use the copy, paste and cut function. I can't seem to figure what is wrong with the code. I have looked at many sources modifying the code and i have come out with the following.

```
from tkinter import *

#Class
class Edit():
    def __init__(self):
        textbox.__init__(self)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copy)
        self.bind('<Control-x>', self.cut)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.paste)

    def copy(self):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        textbox = self.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
        self.clipboard_append(text)

    def cut(self):
        self.copy()
        self.delete("sel.first", "sel.last")

    def paste(self):
        textbox = self.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')
        self.insert('insert', text)
```

These are the edit functions.
The rest of the program is below.

```
#root window
edit = Edit
root = Tk()
root.title("Note")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

textbox = Text(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
textbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

#Menu Bar
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=New)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=Open)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=Save)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", command=Save_as)
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=Close)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=Undo)
editmenu.add_separator()
editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=edit.cut)
editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=edit.copy)
editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=edit.paste)
editmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=Select_All)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index", command=Help_Index)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=About)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)

#Popup menu
menu = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
menu.add_command(label="Copy", command=edit.copy)
menu.add_command(label="Paste", command=edit.paste)

def popup(event):
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

textbox.bind("<Button-3>", popup)

root.mainloop()
```

running the full program throws back an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: **<<paste,copy or cut>>**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I am running python 3.3.3 with windows 8.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but your code works fine in Python 2. Does it still fail for you if you instantiate your Edit class like so: edit = Edit() ?

Comment: Changing to edit=Edit() gives the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\notepad.py", line 67, in <module>
    edit = Edit()
  File "C:\Python33\notepad.py", line 6, in __init__
    textbox.__init__(self)
NameError: global name 'textbox' is not defined

Comment: The `NameError` is because the global named `textbox` hasn't been created yet.

Comment: I have moved the class to just after the textbox is created and moved the edit = Edit() after the class but i now get the error: 
AttributeError: 'Edit' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: @user3389913: you should *not* call `textbox.__init__(self)` unless your class is a subclass of `textbox` assuming `textbox` is a class. `self.clipboard_clear()`, `self.clipboard_append()`, and `self.selection_get()` also will raise an exception because they are not defined.

Comment: removing that line means that edit object has no attribute bind.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: read the posted code -- `textbox = Text(root, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)`.

Comment: @user3389913: What makes you expect the `Edit` object to have a `bind` method?

Comment: Ok.i have read it. but i don't see the problem with that line of code.

Comment: i am rather new to python so haven't really grasped the concept quite get. but i would think that edit needed a bind method because its not part of that, its part of def __init__(self):

Comment: sorry i would think that it doesn't need the bind method

Comment: @martineau: even *more* reason not to call `textbox.__init__` explicitly. Also, OP has `from tkinter import *` at the top; it is not clear at the time of `Edit()` call what is `textbox`.

Comment: removing this line throws back an error: AttributeError: 'Edit' object has no attribute 'bind'

Comment: The code i am trying to use is partly supported by python 3 and partly python 2. Thanks for helping. If anyone knows how to copy and paste using tkinter their help is much appreciated.